# Getting Average(DateDiff) based on Multiple Instances of a Groupby Field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, datediff

Currently I'm trying to grab the average date difference between the start and end datetime of multiple events which occur multiple times within the same month. There are four different types of Event which run for different amounts of time.

```
select
min(datetime) starttime,
max(datetime) endtime,
avg(endtime - min(datetime)) As avg_days,
event
from log_economy_event_point_spending a
AND datetime between '2021-01-01' AND '2021-04-30'
group by event
order by event
```

However, using this method, if the event occurs multiple times it takes the start of the first event, and the end of the last event. How do I write SQL code that can get the average datetime duration of different type of event?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you paste an example input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want:

```
select event,
       min(datetime) as starttime, max(datetime) as endtime,
       (max(datetime) - min(datetime)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) As avg_days
from log_economy_event_point_spending leeps 
where datetime >= '2021-01-01' and
      datetime < '2021-05-01'
group by event
order by event;
```

This fixes the date/time arithmetic to get the average.  Note the other changes:

- The date comparison includes all date/time values in April, which I'm guessing is your intention.  Your version eliminates values on April 30th.
- The table aliases is *meaningful* rather than being an arbitrary letter.
- You cannot re-use column aliases in the expressions in the select where the aliases are defined.

Comment: Thanks for this. However it is not quite it. I have multiple instances of the same event happening throughout the 5 months analysed, so I need to get the average duration of each event as it occurs throughout the months. So Event 1 might happen 4 times, and the duration might vary, while Event 2 might happen 3 times but be always 3 days. Many thanks for your answer.